# Pass multiple values using ajax and echo in another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
function getData(des, poid, divid){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'loaddata.php?des=' + des + '&poid='+poid, //call storeemdata.php to store form data

                success: function(data) {
                    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(divid);
                    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
        }

//Function call
<select name="descr" id="descr" onchange="getData(this.value,this.value,   'displaydata')">
```

This is the code and I passed multiple values in url. when I try to echo those values in next page it echo only one value (des) two times.Any help would be appreciated.

```
$slno = $_GET['des'];
$poid = $_GET['poid'];
echo $slno;
echo $poid;
```

Comment: also post code where the getData() will get call...

Comment: I agree that it seems like the error is in the actual calling of getData can you see the url being called in the request?

Comment: <select name="descr" id="descr" onchange="getData(this.value,this.value, 'displaydata')"> This is the code @pAsh

Comment: your answer shows your passing the same variable (this.value) twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. Thanks to everyone who looked into it to help me. Here is the code and it works like a charm.

```
function getData(des, divid){
    var poid = $("select[name='poid']").val();//this line pass second value "poid" in my case
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'loaddata.php?',
                data: {des : des, poid : poid},
                success: function(data) {
                    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(divid);
                    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
        }
```

function call

```
<select name="des" id="des" onchange="getData(this.value, 'displaydata')">
```

ajax.php file

```
$slno = $_GET['des'];
$pid1 = $_GET['poid'];
echo $slno;
echo $pid1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`<select name="descr" id="descr" onchange="getData(this.value,this.value, 'displaydata')">`

The issue is that in the display data function you are setting the des and poid url variables to the same value as shown in your code above.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @jesse. Can you please show me how to?

Comment: for the second parameter it would be a long line becase you would need to get the value of the other select with document.getElementbyid

Comment: Thanks @jesse. I'll try that and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass ass second param inner text from option tag instead of the same value. To do this you can just use:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Comment: Thanks @Arkowsky. I'm trying to pass another value from another dropdown as well. I don't this this will work.

Comment: Can you show us more code? I mean how did you try implement this passing text from option in html

Comment: First I choose poid from a drop down and by matching poid I fetched des in another drop down. On selecting des these values should be passed by ajax.
poid
        <select name="poid" onchange="javascript: submit()" >
It reloads page and fetxh data in des..

des
       <select name="descr" id="descr" onchange="getData(this.value,this.value, 'displaydata')">