# How to refresh particular div when onclick without losing dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to fetch data when onclick is invoked. I have four div in my form and I want only a particular div to be reloaded and fetch data. while loading it should not discard the form data. Anyone help. Thanks in advance for people who are going to help me in this.

my code looks something like this

```
<div id="fetch">
<?php
//query to fetch data
?>
</div>
<div id="data4">
//dynamic data
//Want to retain this data even after fetch
</div>
```

Comment: For few text maybe just a javascsript var like `var data = $("#data4").html();` for more you should look to sessionStorage [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: when clicking on div#fetch, use an ajax request to fetch data from a separate php script. On ajax.success, change the text in  div#fetch to the received data

Comment: Thanks @Core972 That was informative. But didn't solve my code :)

Comment: I tried that too @Cashbee. But i'm facing problem in passing multiple values through ajax. [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820911/pass-multiple-values-using-ajax-and-echo-in-another-page)

Comment: pass data with ajax like this `data: {var1: 'value1', var2: 'value2'},`

Comment: @Cashbee Tried that too. there is a problem in function call and I cant get through. :(

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use AJAX.
Onclick you can send a xmlhttprequest (JS) to a separate php file, which returns the data you need (for example as string / JSON), and insert it into your website with JS.

Example:

```
function test()
  {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
      {
        result = xhr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("test_field").innerHTML = result;
      }
    }
    xhr.open("GET","your_ajax_file.php",true);
    xhr.send();
  }
```

your_ajax_file.php returns the data you want to insert.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. K. O. Rolling but I want to pass two parameters to ajax_file.php. how do I do that.
I have tried something similar [here. check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820911/pass-multiple-values-using-ajax-and-echo-in-another-page) this and if you can help me I would be grateful.

Comment: you can pass your variables as GET parameters like this: xhr.open("GET","your_ajax_file.php?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2",true);

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have a problem with function call, but you did not give more information. so i will give you an example how to write an ajax request, then you can maybe give me more detailed info on where your problem is.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_file.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {var1: 'value1', var2: 'value2'},
    success: function( data ){
        console.log('ajax request successful! data: '+data);
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
```

And in your ajax_file.php do something like this:

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];

echo $var1.', '$var2;
```

edit: typo, changed val2 to var2 in ajax request

Comment: [Can you answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820911/pass-multiple-values-using-ajax-and-echo-in-another-page) @Cashbee. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820911/pass-multiple-values-using-ajax-and-echo-in-another-page) is the code that I was talking about